# How to trim only white space but not \n in Java

Tags: java

I have a string like

`String str = " hello world\n "`

when I call str.trim(),
it returns

`"hello world"`

However, I need the string looks like

`"hello world\n"`

How could I do it for only remove leading and trailing white space in a string?

Comment: Maybe replace? `str.replaceAll("(^ +)|( +$)", "")`

Comment: You could setup the regex as above, but the '\n' is white space. What should happen if you have `"hello\n "` or `"hello \n"`. As the problem is stated, I would use .trim, then add a \n back to the string.

Comment: @ernest_k Regex is a bit of an overkill for such a simple task.

Comment: What should happen if you have `"hello world\n\n"` ? What should happen if you have "\nhello\nworld\n"?

Answer (score 2):

Try using this but replace Character.isWhitespace with your own implementation of what should be tracked as whitespace

```
public static String trim(String s) {
     return ltrim(rtrim(s));
}

public static Boolean isWhitespace(char c) {
     return Character.isWhitespace(c);
}

public static String ltrim(String s) {
     int i = 0;
     while (i < s.length() && isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
         i++;
     }
     return s.substring(i);
}

public static String rtrim(String s) {
    int i = s.length()-1;
    while (i >= 0 &&  isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
        i--;
    }
    return s.substring(0,i+1);
}
```

Comment: There is also `Character.isSpaceChar('\n')`, which returns `false` for `\n`

Comment: Can you explain why this is a better solution to just escaping the backslash?

Comment: @Matthew, \n is a special character, not a part of the string

Comment: Maybe I am just really stupid but this whole ordeal is confusing me. He said his string is declared like so `String str = " hello world\n "`,

Comment: @Matthew which means we have 2 lines string with the first line " hello world" and the second one " "

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all **\n** character with **\\n.** then trim it. after trimming replace **'\\n'** with \n

```
String str = " hello world\n ";
str=str.replace("\n", "\\n");          // replace '\n' with '\\n'

System.out.println(str);  

str=str.trim();                       // trim it
System.out.println(str);

str=str.replace("\\n", "\n");          // reverse it
System.out.println(str);

System.out.println("end");            // to see new line
```

**Output:**

```
 hello world

 hello world\n 
hello world\n
hello world

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do.

```
private static Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[\t ]*(.*?)[\t ]*", Pattern.DOTALL);

public static String stripWhiteStuff(String str) {
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(str);
    return m.matches()? m.group(1) : str;
}

public static void main(String... args) {

    String str = "  Hello\n\t ";
    System.out.println(">" + stripWhiteStuff(str) + "<");
}
```

Result:

```
>Hello
<
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression with the character to remove.

Here's a pretty simple code that works.

```
String s = "  Hello world\n      ";
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(^ +)|( +$)", ""));
```

Output

```
  Hello world\n      
Hello world\n
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to escape the backslash so it gets treated like a literal:

```
String str = " hello world\\n ";
System.out.println(str.trim());
```

**Output**

`hello world\n`

Comment: I want it to be newline \n, not string \\n

Comment: I don't understand what that means. You said you want to trim your `String` to look like this *"hello world\n"*, by escaping the `\\` symbol it will be treated like a literal. Run the code and see for yourself.

Comment: The string is just from outside, I can only receive it and want to keep the \n

Comment: They want the newline character to remain in the string, as a newline character.

Comment: @matt Well that should have been explained better in the question itself then, there was absolutely no mention of that being a requirement. I guess I will just wait for this to answer to hit -3 so I can get the `peer pressure` badge.

Comment: Yes the question could have been explained better. It still isn't clear what they want either.

Comment: sorry for not well explained, I found in java that all the characters <= ' '(ascII 0x20) will be trimed

Comment: @Jimmy Guo Yea I get it now, I recommend updating your question so it makes it clear what it is that you actually want.